# Change only MenuItem Radiobutton and Checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, menuitem, controltemplate

for separator it is possible, to change only this, which are included in MenuItem.
therefor I had to use:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}" x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}">
```

is there some thing like this for menuitem and RadioButton?
the other problem is, that this only works correctly under windows7 and not under windows XP.
I Post the whole Code later, but i had not to specify the separator with the key. it works so - under windows7. at windows xp the color is changed to, but a strange transparent border is about the whole seperator. But i draw only 1 border for fill it with the color in my separator control template and not two!

can i find somewhere the child-"stylekey"'s for MenuItem? vs has at this point no intelligence.

Answer (score 0):

here is the full code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Separator}" x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Menu}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                            Height="2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

the problem with windows xp was, that i has not override the default style.

the other question with the radio buttons and checkbox is always there

an other problem is, that i had to override the default style for a grid'S background. i had to draw a line at the grid's background with a color and include the default content.
the line should not added manually at each window, the should be at the same position at each window of the application.

but the line should only be a line and not fill the whole window, i don't know the width and high of the window. can i maybe use the  ? is there any example?